# Datetime class and making a difference of datetimes

Tags: c#

I want to make a difference between e_time and duration but how can I? Since the variables are declared as strings ...
the code is here

```
string e_time = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);
string uname = ClientInformation.username;
string duration = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
```

Comment: What is `ts` by the way? I don't understand your quesiton. Also what is the value of `uname` exactly? You want to difference between `e_time` and `uname` as an hour, minute etc..?

Comment: i was making a simple program that checks the user for log on period/session (i.e, for how long time does the user is on the system so the uname is for the user name but i want the difference b/n e_time which is the current PC time and duration is the counting time from log on to logout period , and e_time -duration  will give me the exact start time of the user). however the variables are declared in strings and i cant perform the difference operation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `ts` is a `System.TimeSpan` from the properties it exposes, and that you want to find out when something started? In that case, `TimeSpan` exposes a good `-` operator:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now - ts;
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all Parse the above strings to datetime and then use TimeSpan for find the diffrence

```
TimeSpan diffrence=duration-e_time
```

Comment: yeah tnx but after parsing the variables and make a breakpoint to check the values, the parsed value of 'duration'and 'e_time' has a true value but the variable 'diffrence' has no value (00:00:00) and how can i solve this problem ??

Comment: And my new question is after the date is saved into the database it has a different value in the hour format (i.e the true value was 04 hour which is 10 local time but after it has been saved to local database it says 16 but the rest are correct value which are the minute and seconds .)

Comment: please ask new question with full description so that everybody contribute.. when you post your question. post a comment on this answer that you post new question